# Gmail sends email with wrong name

Tags: email, google-api, gmail, spf, google-workspace

I just set up an email account on G-Suite and its like that:

```
Name: MyDomain.com
Email: info@mydomain.com
```

However when I send email from this email account it is displayed as:

```
Name: AnotherDomain.com
```

I don't have this domain on G-Suite a long time ago and don't know why it fetches this wrong name from it. Any ideas?

I tried adding an SPF record, but it doesn't solve the problem:

```
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

Comment: https://it.umn.edu/services-technologies/how-tos/gmail-incorrect-display-name

Answer (score 5):

The username must be a valid account in your domain. Read more at G-Suite APIs Gmail [Users Settings](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962?hl=en).

> - Sign in to the Google Admin console.
> - From the dashboard, click Apps.
> - Click G Suite > Gmail > User settings.
> - In the Catch-all address section, select the Forward the mail to: option.
> - Enter the username for the catch-all address. The username must be a valid account in your domain. Don’t include the domain name, **@your-domain**. It’s automatically added to the address.
> - At the bottom, click Save.
>
> If you want to bounce messages addressed to nonexistent recipients:
>
> - Sign in to the Google Admin console.
> - From the dashboard, click Apps.
> - Click G Suite > Gmail > User settings.
> - In the Catch-all address section, select the Discard option.
> - At the bottom, click Save.